# Golang: Strange behaviour with function type

Tags: go, goroutine

Obviously, I have a race condition in my go code. But I cannot find it as I'm pretty sure to be synchronizing correctly. After hours of debugging, you probably can help me find it.

First of all, here's my (very simplified) code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Parser struct {
    callback    Callback
    callbackSet chan bool
    test        int
}

func NewParser() Parser {
    p := Parser{}
    p.test = 100
    p.callbackSet = make(chan bool)
    return p
}

func (p *Parser) SetCallback(newCallback Callback) {
    log.Println("=> SET CALLBACK: ", newCallback)
    p.test = 100
    p.callback = newCallback
    log.Println("=> SETTING CALLBACK DONE")
    p.callbackSet <- true
}

func (p *Parser) StartParsing() {
    go p.parse()
}



func (p *Parser) parse() {
    cb := <-p.callbackSet
    _ = cb
    log.Println("Verify Callback: ", p.callback)
    log.Println("Verify Test Variable: ", p.test)

    funcDone := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) // Some io-Operation here
        funcDone <- true
    }()

    _ = <-funcDone
}

type Callback func(Message)
type Message int

type Dialog struct {
    Parser  Parser
}
func CreateDialog() (Dialog, error) {
    d := Dialog{}
    d.Parser = NewParser()
    d.Parser.StartParsing()
    return d, nil
}

func (d *Dialog) OnMessage(callback Callback) {
    log.Println("dialog.OnMessage: ", callback)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) // This sleep is just to prove the synchronization. It could be removed.
    d.Parser.SetCallback(callback)
}

func main() {

    dialog, _ := CreateDialog()
    dialog.OnMessage(func(m Message){
        log.Println("Message: ", m)
    })

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second) // Not clean but just to await all of the output
}
```

The big question now is: Why is `p.callback` `<nil>` in `p.parse` whereas `p.test` isn't, although these two are set at the very same time?

And the stuff should be synchronized using the channel `p.callbackSet`?!

Fully runnable example at https://play.golang.org/p/14vn5Tie5Y

I tried replacing the main function by a simpler one. I suspect the bug to be somewhere in the `Dialog` struct. When I circumvent its usage I'm unable to reproduce the issue:

```
func main() {
    p := NewParser()
    p.StartParsing()
    p.SetCallback(func (m Message) {
        log.Println("Message: ", m)
    })

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second) // Not clean but just to await all of the output
}
```

The rest of the code remains the same. Another playable example of the modified (working) version here: https://play.golang.org/p/0Y0nKbfcrv

Comment: My answer is (currently) wrong, but I looked through the playground: the problem isn't exclusive to `p.callback`, as if you try to change `p.test` in `SetCallback()` it prints the default value later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are storing the `Parser` object by value and returning a `Dialog` by value from `CreateDialog`.

The original `Parser` instance created inside `CreateDialog` becomes lost when the `Dialog` instance is returned by value.

It is the original `Parser` that is parsing, and receives the callback as logged.

```
func CreateDialog() (Dialog, error) {
    d := Dialog{}
    d.Parser = NewParser()
    d.Parser.StartParsing() // <-- this instance is parsing
    return d, nil
}

func main() {
   dialog, _ := CreateDialog()
   // dialog.Parser <-- this is now a new instance which is NOT parsing
   dialog.OnMessage(func(m Message){
       log.Println("Message: ", m)
   })
}
```

Therefore to fix it you can do one of three:

1) Call `StartParsing` in `main`.

```
func main() {
    dialog, _ := CreateDialog()
    dialog.Parser.StartParsing();
    dialog.OnMessage(func(m Message){
        log.Println("Message: ", m)
    })
 }
```

2) Store `Parser` as a pointer in Dialog:

```
func NewParser() *Parser {
    p := &Parser{}
    p.test = 100
    p.callbackSet = make(chan bool)
    return p
}

type Dialog struct {
    Parser  *Parser
}
```

3) Return `Dialog` as a pointer in from `CreateDialog`:

```
func CreateDialog() (*Dialog, error) {
    d := &Dialog{}
    d.Parser = NewParser()
    d.Parser.StartParsing()
    return d, nil
}
```

That should fix it.

Comment: By "The original `Parser` instance created inside `CreateDialog` becomes lost when the `Dialog` instance is returned by value.", do you mean that `Parser` in the dialog object becomes replaced by a new default-valued Parser object?

Comment: The `Parser` in the dialog and all of it's properties are copied over by value. Therefore the `test` value of 100 is copied, the `callback` value of nil is copied, and the `callbackSet` channel (an implicit reference type) is copied. You can see this for yourself by putting `log.Println` statements in `CreateDialog` and `main`.